# How do I configure IIS so that websocket conenctions are handled by an external program?

Tags: iis, websocket, iis-10

I can't really get my head around how websockets are configured and expected to work on the server.

In my case I have a machine (Windows 10) running IIS. On that machine I want to place my own websocket server application (WS-Server.exe), which should accept websocket connections from my client web app (WS-Client).

Doing all this on `localhost` without IIS involved is pretty stragihtforward - simply make WS-Server.exe listen on some specific port, for example `5004`, and have WS-Client (the web app) connect to `ws://127.0.0.1:5400`.

But now I want to deploy it and make it reachable over the Internet, and here's where I get lost. I understand that the Websocket handshake can be made via a normal HTTP call to IIS on port 80, and the connection will then be "upgraded" to a websocket connection by IIS **if IIS is properly configured**.

1. How do I properly configure IIS to enable websockets? I tried following the steps on [Microsofts website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket) to enable Websockets in IIS, but I'm not sure if that is all that is needed? When I try to connect to `127.0.0.1:80` from WS-Client I get an error message saying `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`. As I understand it, a websocket "HTTP upgrade" response should have response code `101`? So it seems IIS is just serving a normal webpage instead?
2. How do I tell IIS that I want all websocket connections to go to WS-Server.exe, which is running on the same machine? Do I need to tell IIS that I want `5004` to be used as the websocket port somehow? It seems like this step is always missing in all guides I've found, which I don't understand - what good is a websocket connection if you don't have something running on the server machine to actually send out data on it?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support#disable-websocket-when-using-socketio-on-nodejs You might get some ideas from this.

Comment: @LexLi Unfortunately not. I have read those, but I still don't get it. Most of the instructions seem to be for Windows Server 2012, which looks different and has different features from Windows 10. The linked blog post about `IWebSocketContext` - I have no idea what to do with? I have a Websocket server program written in Delphi - it's simply an `exe`, and I need to somehow make it reachable from the internet using IIS (I guess?).